# Converting from R to Python, trying to understand a line

Tags: python, r

I have a fairly simple question. I have been converting some statistical analysis code from R to Python. Up until now, I have been doing just fine, but I have gotten stuck on this particular line:

```
nlsfit <- nls(N~pnorm(m, mean=mean, sd=sd),data=data4fit,start=list(mean=mu, sd=sig), control=list(maxiter=100,warnOnly = TRUE))
```

Essentially, the program is calculating the non-linear least-squares fit for a set of data, the "nls" command. In the original text, the "tilde" looks like an "enye", I'm not sure if that is significant.

As I understand the equivalent of pnorm in Python is norm.cdf from from scipy.stats. What I want to know is, what does the "tilde/enye" do before the pnorm function is invoked. "m" is a predefined variable, while "mean" and "sd" are not.

I also found some code, essentially reproducing nls in Python: [nls Python code](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-vs-python-practical-data-analysis-nonlinear-regression/), however, because of the date of the post (2013), I was wondering if there are any more recent equivalents, preferably written in Pyton 3.

Any advice is appreiated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from `?nls`: the first argument in `nsl` is `formula`:

> formula: a nonlinear model formula including variables and parameters.
>   Will be coerced to a formula if necessary

Now, if you do `?formula`, we can read this:

> The models fit by, e.g., the lm and glm functions are specified in a
>   compact symbolic form. The ~ operator is basic in the formation of
>   such models. An expression of the form y ~ model is interpreted as a
>   specification that the response y is modelled by a linear predictor
>   specified symbolically by model

Therefore, the `~` in your case `nls` join the response/dependent/regressand variable in the left with the regressors/explanatory variables in the right part of your nonlinear least squares.

Best!

Answer (score 1):

This minimizes

```
sum((N - pnorm(m, mean=mean, sd=sd))^2)
```

using starting values for `mean` and `sd` specified in `start`.  It will perform a maximum of 100 iterations and it will  return instead of signalling an error in the case of termination before convergence.

The first argument to `nls` is an R `formula` which specifies the regression where the left hand side of the tilde (`N`) is the dependent variable and the right side is the function of the parameters (`mean`, `sd`) and data (`m`) used to predict it.

Note that `formula` objects do not have a fixed meaning in R but rather each function can interpret them in any way it likes.  For example, `formula` objects used by `nls` are interpreted differently than `formula` objects used by `lm`. In `nls` the formula `y ~ a + b * x` would be used to specify a linear regression but in `lm` the same regression would be expressed as `y ~ x` .

See `?pnorm`, `?nls`, `?nls.control` and `?formula` .